# Setup local environment for site that has Wordpress and theme files in separate subdirectories?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, testing, configuration

I'm at a total loss here. I've never seen a Wordpress site setup with the `wp-content` files and the `wordpress` install files in separate sub-directories. Here's a snapshot of the root directory so you can see the file directories. The `content` folder includes the parent and child theme, and the `wp` folder includes the wordpress install.

[snapshot of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTGq2.png)

I'm using a `MAMP` as my local environment, and I've grabbed the live site files via `SFTP`. At the root of the directly is an `.htaccess` file, `local-config.php` and `wp-config.php`. For my local setup, I want to host this site at `localhost:8888/{ project name }`, however the config files aren't connecting for me.

This is what `local-config.php` includes:

```
<?php

 /* This is a sample local-config.php file In it, you *must* include
 the four main database defines

 You may include other settings here that you only want enabled on your
 local development checkouts
 */

 // Must have a trailing and leading slash // define('WP_SUBURI',
 '/mysite/');

 define( 'DB_NAME', 'icecreamstore_wp' ); define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
 define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'root' ); define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

 // Comma separated list of hostnames which should be considered
 "local" // and re-written to $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. Also addresses
 wp-content => content replacement. define( 'PATHFIX',
 'local.icecreamstore.maine.edu, icecreamstore.maine.edu'
 );

 // WP_ENV sets the environment to be used by the wp-env MU plugin //
  defined( 'WP_ENV', 'development' );

 // Maintenance mode using the maintenance mu-plugin // define(
 'MAINTENANCE', false); // define( 'MAINTENANCE', true); // define(
 'MAINTENANCE', '<h1>Custom message</h1><p>For maintenance mode</p>');

 // $table_prefix = 'wp_';

 // If the keys are defined here, they will not be loaded in
 wp-config.php

 { security and authentication below this line... }
```

And the `wp-config.php` site includes:

```
 <?php
 // ===================================================
 // Load database info and local development parameters
 // ===================================================
 if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/local-config.php' ) ) {
   include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/local-config.php' );
 }

 // ========================
 // Security
 // ========================
 if ( !defined('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT') )
   define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', TRUE);
 if ( !defined('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS') )
   define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', FALSE);

 // ========================
 // Custom Content Directory
 // ========================
 define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content' );

 if ( !defined('WP_SUB_URI') )
   define('WP_SUBURI', '/');

 define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . WP_SUBURI   . 'content' );

 /** dynamically set siteurl and home options */
 define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . WP_SUBURI . 'wp');
 define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . WP_SUBURI);

 { security and authentication below... }
```

And just in case it helps, the `.htaccess` at the root includes:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

Help! I haven't found anyone online with this particular issue of having to take a live site setup this way, and create a local environmnet for testing. The downside: The previous developer didn't include anything in the `README.md` docs.

Comment: Hi@Kedmasterk you can refer  https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/wordpress-local-dev-tips/

Comment: @Samyappa I can see the homepage, but I cannot see the product pages. The category base name does not appear, but instead takes me back to localhost on MAMP. Any ideas why?